# Apache Camel and read-only message queue

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

So I'm using the SQS combined with Apache Camel. Some messages have references to s3 object. I need to route this messages to another queue, but the problem is that I have to process associated with this message s3 object without message modification.

The workflow is

1. Get message with body["ref":"some-ref"] from `queue-1`
2. Get S3 object associated with the message.
3. If s3 object contains `option` pass the message to `queue-2`
4. If s3 object doesn't contain `option` pass the message to `queue-3`.

And I faced with the problem that `.process` method modify message body.

```
 from("queue-1")
                .choice()
                .when(header("option").isNotNull())
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            //FETCH S3 OBJECT                            }
                    })
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                       //CHECK IF OBJECT HAS SOME OPTIONS
                        }
                    }).to("queue-2")
                .when(header("option").isNull())
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {               
                        //CHECK IF BODY HAS SOME OPTIONS
                        }
                    }).to("queue-3)
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Unknown");
```

So Is there a solution that can store message without modifying it?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And what is being modified on the message. And what do you do in those processor methods?

Comment: @Murmav, If you do not change in/out body of exchange in your processors(depends of your code) then message should be unchanged